# HTTP auth and Flex

Tags: apache-flex, http

I have a small query. I wrote a Flex Application with PHP remoting using ZendAMF. i also made and auth system. User provides credentials and i pass them to my gateway where i have a service registered to query a SQL db and verify if the user is registered or not. Thats working perfectly. In my application i am loading MRTG graphs (PNG Files) into Image component. The GRAPHS are inside my Document Root. They are also loading well. Problem is if i type the URL path to the png file i can see it directly without any authentication. to cater that i added htaccess file to MRTG folder inside my document root. Know when i view the images inside my Flex App it asks for HTTP username and password. which i dont want.

In simple words . MRTG PNG's are inside my document root

1. Can i move them out of document root and still have my Flex App access them ( i tried and failed with that)
2. I just want the user to be able to view MRTG pngs  and not directly from URL.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ZendAMF, why don't you just create a service method on your service that provides you with those images?

That way you have full control over what happens.
For example you could send them through as a byte array or a base64 encoded string, making it a lot harder to define where the image is actually stored on server disk.

Cheers

Comment: but in this way image will still be inside my Document Root. ?? right.

Comment: The images could be anywhere on your server.
Also, you could then just restrict access to that folder if the user is not authenticated correctly.